# Will the app gets rejected for “Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions for <ViewController>"

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

Here is the error I got when I run my Application
Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions for

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because [we are not Apple customer support](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get this error when an other animation has started before the previous animation was completed. I think apple won't reject due to this error. Because due to this error only your UI will get distorted, your app will not crash.